# Whats the difference between just 'map' and 'mapView' ? Anyways to combine them together?

Tags: swiftui, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I found the code to annotate on map after running the code but unable to combine with my main code. My main code uses map( .... ) to int the map on mapkit but the annotation code is using 'MapView' as shown below,

MapView version of int Map on SwiftUI

```
MapView(centerCoordinate: $centerCoordinate, annotations: locations)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
```

Map version of int Map on SwiftUI

```
Map(coordinateRegion: $viewModel.region,
                    interactionModes: .all,
                    showsUserLocation: true,
                    annotationItems: annotationItems)
```

The code I got is able to take in user values in Double (Lat and Long) and annotate on the map.

I am more comfortable using the map(...) setup but the annotation I got is from mapView which is another set up.

I have difficulties combing them together.

I can annotate on the map before running the code ,but what I want is update after int the map and I cannot seem to find the code to annotate for the map( ...) format.

The mapview(...) verision is ,

```
Button(action: {
                        let savedLat = Double(textFieldLat) // Lat value
                        let savedLong = Double(textFieldLong) // Long value
                        let newLocation = MKPointAnnotation()
                        newLocation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: savedLat ?? 0, longitude: savedLong ?? 0)
                        self.locations.append(newLocation) 
                        
                    })
```

Update the map

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable{
...
...
...
    func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        if annotations.count != view.annotations.count {
            view.addAnnotations(annotations)
        
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: How to put annotations in the SwiftUI Map is on the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mapmarker) before you copy and paste code you should examine the code and truly understand what it is doing. Your first place to look to understand something should be the the official documentation.

Comment: I followed the example on the link you sent. I get "Missing argument for parameter 'place' in call" on my struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

Comment: Thanks, the link is helpful but I still cant manage to run my code.

Answer (score 0):

#### The difference between Map and MKMapView

`Map` is a native SwiftUI view that embeds a map interface according to [SwiftUI's Map doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/map), whereas `MKMapView` is a class for an embeddable map interface ([doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview)). I don't think you can combine them -
[this post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/716834?answerId=732453022#732453022) in Apple's dev forums suggests using `MKMapView` if `Map` is unable to meet your needs, or submitting a feature request.

#### In practice, `Map` is easier to use and can be dynamically updated

Map is designed to be simpler to use. I was also looking for how to add annotation markers to `Map` XCode's MapKit and SwiftUI tutorials, the official documentation lacks helpful examples.

Here's a code sample of how I was able to initialize then dynamically update the marker based on passing in a coordinate. If you need to render multiple markers, you could instead add additional items to the `markers` list and then iterate over each of them like [this example in the apple forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651668?answerId=616530022#616530022).

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct Marker: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var location: MapMarker
}

struct MapView: View {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
   
    @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion()
    @State var markers = [Marker(location: MapMarker(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -96.8311, longitude: 145.0602), tint: .blue))]
    
    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: markers) { marker in
            marker.location }
            .onAppear {
                setRegion(coordinate)
            }
    }
    
    private func setRegion(_ coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
         region = MKCoordinateRegion(
             center: coordinate,
             span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2)
         )
         markers = [Marker(location: MapMarker(coordinate: coordinate, tint: .blue))]
     }
}

struct MapView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MapView(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -36.8311, longitude: 145.0602))
    }
}
```